# Collection of Tuple in Java

Tags: java, collections

If i need to store a flattened  collection of tuples in Java,is there an option?
eg I wish to store a store the empid,name,salary in a collection for a quick lookup and dispatch by email.

```
list=[(1,shawn,2000),
(2,rohan,1500),
.....]
```

An one-pass access to each flattened entry makes it quick.

Comment: Just create a class.

Comment: Or store it as formated json strings

Answer (score 0):

Use Java Tuples library.

javatuples offers you tuple classes from one to ten elements:

- Unit`<A>` (1 element)
- Pair`<A,B>` (2 elements)
- Triplet`<A,B,C>` (3 elements)
- Quartet`<A,B,C,D>` (4 elements)
- Quintet`<A,B,C,D,E>` (5 elements)
- Sextet`<A,B,C,D,E,F>` (6 elements)
- Septet`<A,B,C,D,E,F,G>` (7 elements)
- Octet`<A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H>` (8 elements)
- Ennead`<A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I>` (9 elements)
- Decade`<A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J>` (10 elements)

Reference : http://www.javatuples.org/